# How can I calculate the time complexity of my algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I want to know the time complexity of my code. How can I calculate it?

```
{
    int q;
    int w;
    cout <<"please enter values" <<endl; 
    cin>>q;
    for(w = 0; w<q; w++)
    {
        int p; 
        int o;
        int sum = 0;
        cin>>p;
        for(o = 0; o < p; o++)
        {
            int x; 
            int y;
            int z;
            cin>>x ;
            cin >>y;
            cin>>z;
            sum = sum + (x*z);
        }
        cout<<sum<<endl;
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you should show us some attempts of yours so that we can see what's your problem with it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine simplex time complexity (ie Max flow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650426/how-to-determine-simplex-time-complexity-ie-max-flow)

Answer (score 0):

The first `for` loop will run `q` times, which is a time complexity of **O(q)**.
The second (inner) `for` loop will run `p` times, thus, it has a time complexity of **O(p)** and since it is called once for every run of the first loop, their complexities multiply like this:

**O(q) * O(p) = O(q * p)**

In general, nested loops multiply and consecutive loops add.